# Why is ruby on rails returning null instead of json object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails so this is really basic and I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  I'm trying to send some JSON to an action and get it to return a response in JSON.  A simplified version of what I'm trying is below.

The jQuery I'm using:

```
var request = { 'voter': { 'voter_name': 'John', 'voter_email': 'john@john.com'} };

var url = 'http://someip/Voters/create';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: request,
    success: function (data) { alert(data); },
    error: function (data) { alert(data); },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

My action:

```
def create
    @voter = Voter.new(params[:voter])

    logger.info(@voter.to_json)

    render :json => @voter
end
```

It seems like this should be returning just fine, especially considering the console is showing the Voter object just fine:

```
Processing VotersController#create (for someip at 2010-08-17 21:19:51) [POST]  
Parameters: {"voter"=>{"voter_name"=>"John", "voter_email"=>"john@john.com"}}
{"voter":{"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"voter_email":"john@john.com","voter_name":"John"}}
Completed in 11ms (View: 1, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://someip/Voters/create]
```

The problem is that my alerts (or any other way I try to look at this data) are all showing me null.  No object is being returned.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you see if hit that action with `curl`?  Is the response empty?

Comment: I'm stuck on a windows box at the moment so that's a very good question.  If I access that action directly in my browser with a GET I'm seeing:  

{"voter":{"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"voter_email":null,"voter_name":null}}

Comment: Is the url you're posting to on a different domain from the page doing the posting?

Comment: It's actually all by IP at this point.  It will be different domains eventually.  What's weird is the server is definitely getting the POST though since I've even had it write to sqlite.  It's just not responding with anything.

Comment: Could you include a snippet from your development log that shows the POST request hitting your `create` action?

Comment: Updated the original question to contain it.  Should have included that originally, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the log. If you inspect the Ajax response in Firebug or similar, does it show the JSON?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond.  The response (from Firebug) is totally empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert the instance to JSON before rendering. Like this:

```
render :json => @voter.to_json
```

Just like you do in your debug log output.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried that and it didn't seem to make a difference.